# Parametric vs Non-parametric test recommendation

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, parametric

What type of non-parametric test would be suitable for the dataset shown in the image:
[image: description]

The sample size is 200 each for both variables. The data value can vary from 0-4 for both variables. The histogram or Q-Q plot doesn't show any normalcy. Hence, I also tried to use Mann-Whitney U test where I defined both variables as ordinal. However, SPSS is unable to compute any test statistics. I am looking for some recommendation.

Comment: What is the question you are hoping to answer from the data?

Comment: The data are not the only thing when it comes to choosing a test; it depends on other things. What is the precise question of interest / what null hypothesis and alternative you want to test? Are these Likert type items? Did you *want* to treat them as ordinal or did you have it in mind to treat them as interval? Are the values actually paired?

Comment: And what do the rows represent?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to see if there are statistically significant difference between the mean of the two variables. Yes, these are Likert type items. The null hypothesis would be there is no statistical difference between the two variables. The values are independent, and I would like to treat them as ordinal. The two variables are coming from independent population and each participant selected a value from 0-4.

Comment: And by chance, the two independent samples are of equal size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the data are responses to a Likert-type item with four response options, it's best to treat the data as ordinal.  It probably doesn't even make sense to think of the mean of such a variable.  That is, you can't take an average, of, say, responses that are "Never", "Rarely", "Frequently", "All the time".

A simple approach would be the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test mentioned in the question.  Note that this test is not usually a test of the mean or median, but tests if the responses in one group tend to be higher than in the other group.

You could also use a test of the median, like Mood's median test.  But I'll warn you that this test can get funky when you have discrete responses, like you have.

As to why you aren't getting results from SPSS, I wouldn't know.  But the test is easy enough in Jamovi or even R or Python.

***ADDITION:***

You can run the following in R or at https://rdrr.io/snippets/ without installing software.

At least for the data you supplied --- if I got the numbers correct --- here's what I get.

For these samples, the item "p" tends to have higher values than "g" --- more "4"'s, and fewer "0"'s and "2"'s,

```
Item1_g = c(3,4,4,3,3,4,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,3,4,3,4,0,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,3,2)
Item1_p = c(3,3,3,4,4,3,4,3,3,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,4,3,4,3,3)

wilcox.test(Item1_g, Item1_p)

   ### Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
   ### W = 457.5, p-value = 0.2087

library(rcompanion)

vda(x=Item1_g, y=Item1_p, verbose=TRUE)

   ###            Statistic Value
   ### 1 Proportion Ya > Yb 0.193
   ### 2 Proportion Ya < Yb 0.353
   ### 3    Proportion ties 0.455

Data = data.frame(Y = factor(c(Item1_g, Item1_p), 
                             levels=c("0","1","2","3","4")), 
                  Group = c(rep("Item1_g", length(Item1_g)),
                            rep("Item1_p", length(Item1_p))))

round(prop.table(xtabs(~ Group + Y, data=Data), margin=1),2)

   ###            Y
   ###  Group      0    1    2    3    4
   ###  Item1_g 0.03 0.00 0.06 0.45 0.45
   ###  Item1_p 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.42 0.58
```

This additional code will create a bar plots to compare the two groups.

```
library(lattice)

histogram(~ Y | Group,
          data=Data,
          layout=c(1,2),
          drop.unused.levels=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this answer helps validate I am on the right track. I will try out in python.

Comment: I made an addition to the post.  It's helpful for this kind of data to look at the proportion of each response in each group, either by bar plot or a table of proportions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: If the data are paired, the rank difference test is in order, and it handles ties better than the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.  See [this](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar#sec-nonpar-rd) and a section below that on how to use the proportional odds model for paired data.  This allows for extreme ties in the data.

Comment: I am able to compute the p-values using python (I am not familiar with R). I am now trying to calculate the effect size for this data. I used the Vargha and Delaney 2000 method as implemented in this library: https://pingouin-stats.org/build/html/generated/pingouin.mwu.html. The highest common language effect size I am getting out of all my variables in 0.51. How do I interpret the effect size? Are there any thresholds that distinguish large, medium and small effects?

Comment: Good choice of effect size.  If you looking for "small", "medium", "large", effect size interpretations, they are given in the Vargha and Delaney 2000 article.  And I have them listed here: [rcompanion.org/handbook/F_04.html](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_04.html) . The general interpretation is that it is the probability that an observation in one group is larger than an observation in the other group.  It adds in half the ties, which makes it different than Grissom and Kim's Probability of Superiority.  0.50 is no effect.  1.00 or 0.00 is complete stochastic superiority.

Comment: The rank-biserial correlation, also returned by the function, is a linear transformation of the *VDA* statistic, but ranges from -1 to 1, with 0 being no effect.  So it's similar to *r* in range.

Comment: Also, note with VDA, "larger" is distance from 0.50. So a VDA of 0.20 is relatively large. It's the same as 0.80 is the groups were reversed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answers have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would not run any parametric (e.g. t-test, because data is ordinal - Likert), or non-parametric test (e.g. Mann-Whitney U, because there are way too many ties: the vast majority of the comparisons result in ties).
I would however run a 5x5 contingency table (Chi-2 test of association). This is exactly your situation: categorical variables, and trying to see if the various proportions of the 5 possible outcomes are different; your sample size (100) is also large enough that it should work. However, you have some 0's in that 5x5 table: Chi-2 will not even compute, so you will need to apply Fisher exact to the study of the table

Comment: For ordinal data with many ties, classic rank based tests like Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney and Kruskal-Wallis work reasonably well.  You can compare the results of these tests to ordinal regression with simulation studies.  I have a few results of such simulations here: [rcompanion.org/handbook/E_01.html](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/E_01.html)

Comment: The real question here is if they want to treat the response variable as nominal categorical or ordinal categorical.  Usually, if data can be treated as ordinal, it's better to treat it as ordinal.  But not always.